# How to call two functions in javascipt using "button_name".onclick

Tags: javascript, html, solidity

I have a made a result button in index.html

`<button id="result">results</button>`

Now I want to call two functions by just one button click. My index.js file is :

```
const resultButton = document.getElementById("result");
resultButton.onclick = reset;
resultButton.onclick = results;
```

I've observed that only the second functions executes while the first one doesn't

Comment: `resultButton.onclick = function() {reset();results()}`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Call both functions in the function assigned to [the listener](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/EventTarget/addEventListener).

```js
const resultButton = document.querySelector('#result');
resultButton.addEventListener('click', handleClick);

function handleClick() {
  reset();
  results();
}

function reset() {
  console.log('reset');
}

function results() {
  console.log('results');
}
```

```html
<button id="result">results</button>
```